# Change "backordered" text on WooCommerce order received page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I’m trying to modify the word “reservado” or “backordered” in the order details page.

---

I use the following code, unfortunately without the desired result. The "backordered" text does not change, any advice?

```php
function custom_backorder_message( $text, $product ){
    if ($product->is_on_backorder( 0 ) ) {
        $text = __( 'This item may take 3-4 weeks to deliver' );
    }
    return $text;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'custom_backorder_message', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change it via code you can use the `woocommerce_backordered_item_meta_name` filter hook.

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_backordered_item_meta_name( $string, $item ) {  
    // Replace with new text
    $string = 'My new text';
    
    return $string;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_backordered_item_meta_name', 'filter_woocommerce_backordered_item_meta_name', 10, 2 );
```

But you could also change it in the language file.